# Is it possible to customize magento CSS and JS as our wish?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to change the entire Magneto CSS themes templates to the user wish? How to do it and what are the things to learn for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> app > design > frontend > yourtheme > layout > local.xml

Then add a new file to overrule the default CSS rules:

```
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name><params/></action>
```

You can also add a custom JS file in the same location:

```
 <action method="addJs"><script>custom.js</script></action>
```